# Postulate V implies equidistant postulate

Tags: euclidean-geometry

(A) : The set of points in one side equidistant from a given line forms a line

**Postulate V** : If two lines are drawn which intersect a third in such a way that the sum of the inner angles on one side is *less than two right angles*, then the two lines inevitably must intersect each other on that side if extended far enough

Prove that **postulate V** implies (A)

**Proof :** From postulate I through V, we have Euclid's proposition I.34 i.e. in a parallelogram, the opposites and angles are congruent.

How can we finish the proof ?

Add : This is theorem 3.4 in the book geometry from a differential viewpoint - McCleary

Comment: Probably (A) has some clarification about the points being on the same side of the given line. As written that set is really two lines. You take two points $A,B$ at the same distance from the given line $\ell$. Call $C,D$ the foots of their perpendiculars to $\ell$. From the congruence of the triangles $ACD$ and $BDC$, and of $ADB$ and $BCA$ conclude that the angle $CAB$ (and $DBA$) are right angles too. Now take a third $E$ point at the same distance and on the same side of $\ell$. The analogous argument gives that angle $EAC$ is also a right angle.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.